# Why isn't my LESS compiling?

Tags: less

```
<head>
    <!-- Meta / Boilerplate Stuff -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hey</title>
    <!-- END Meta / Boilerplate Stuff -->

    <!--   LESS + CSS links   -->
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/resource/css/style.less">
    <!-- END LESS + CSS links -->

    <!--   Imported JavaScript  -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Dev-environment only LESS debugging object
        less = {
            env: "development",
            dumpLineNumbers: "all"
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="/resource/js/imports/less.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="/resource/js/imports/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- END Imported JavaScript -->

    <!--   In-house JavaScript   -->
    <script type="text/javascript" href="/resource/js/custom.js"></script>
    <!-- END In-house JavaScript -->
</head>
```

Here's my head element, and the URL: http://boilerplate.samstil.es/

My LESS isn't compiling and I can't for the life of me figure out why. I'm not getting any 404's in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LESS doesn't like the space between the -webkit-linear-gradient and the ( in the vertical-gradient and horizontal-gradient mixins.  Where you have:

```
background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient (left, @startColor, @endColor);
```

you should have

```
background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @endColor);
```

Make sure you do this with the other `background-image` options. I tested this with the online less compiler, available at: http://winless.org/online-less-compiler

Hope this helps!